# NES Game development: ASM6 tutorials?

Tags: assembly, nintendo

I'm a NES development newbie and I've found the Nerdy Nights tutorials really handy, but it uses nesasm. As I understand it, ASM6 is much better than nesasm. Does it have comparable tutorials somewhere that I can look up?

Also, is there an official ASM6 page? The version I have of ASM6 is 1.51 and I have no idea if there's a more recent version.

Comment: you may be able to get the detailed info you're looking for if this question were posted on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: try http://nesdev.parodius.com/bbs for everything nesdev related

Answer (score 2):

The ASM6 download (http://home.comcast.net/~olimar/NES/) has most of the basic language information in the README.TXT file packaged with it. This information spells out the specific unique features in ASM6, but that's where the uniqueness ends. Since ASM6 is simply geared toward 6502 processors and is not NES specific, it can do whatever you program it to do. The good news is, since it's basically just assembly, you can continue to use your nesasm tutorials. Just read up on the specific differences in the languages, like comment syntax or labeling, and you should be good to go.

Also, that version I linked at the top is for ASM6 v1.6. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

As you'll see, there are many different compilers for 6502, some of the most common that I've seen are CA65, ASM6, and NESASM - although there are much more.

Outside of what James as already said I found this very useful in my transition from the Nerdy Nights tutorials and NESASM to ASM6:

ASM6 templates: https://forums.nesdev.com/viewtopic.php?t=6160

I would highly recommend making a nesdev forum account as well - the community was very helpful for my project and newbie questions: https://forums.nesdev.com/index.php?sid=d10c328d91cd38f17b990b178b9adffb